# How can I add suffix icon to Ionic 4 input

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Trying to add show and hide password feature in Ionic 4.
Wondering how can I add suffix icon to ion-input or is there some other way?

Comment: what do you mean by suffix icons?

Comment: An eye making password visible when clicked.

Comment: Did you tried ion-icons?

Comment: Tried with some css. 

Here is my solution

`<ion-icon class="suffix-icon" color="secondary" name="eye-off" slot="end"></ion-icon>`

and with css

`.suffix-icon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried with some css. Here is my solution

`<ion-icon class="suffix-icon" color="secondary" name="eye-off" slot="end"></ion-icon>` and with css

`.suffix-icon { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; }`